# How to export a list of customers per domain?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, users

I got a Craft (-v 3.7.67) Commerce (-v 3.4.20) setup with 4 sites in two domains.

I need to export a list of customers (or users, in my case users are 99% customers) per domain (so users that have created their accounts trough one demain or maybe the domain used for the last login).

What would be your go-to method for this ? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I know I don't think Craft stores the originating site that someone registered on. You'd need to store that information against each user yourself using a custom field.